# Do an operation interactively and it works. Do the same operations programmatically and it fails. Redis, heroku, node

Tags: node.js, heroku, redis, node-redis, ioredis

Here's my interactive session.  It works great.

```
ec2-54-83-60-31.compute-1.amazonaws.com:11729> keys *
1) testkey
ec2-54-83-60-31.compute-1.amazonaws.com:11729> flushall
OK
ec2-54-83-60-31.compute-1.amazonaws.com:11729> keys *
ec2-54-83-60-31.compute-1.amazonaws.com:11729> watch testkey
OK
ec2-54-83-60-31.compute-1.amazonaws.com:11729> multi
OK
ec2-54-83-60-31.compute-1.amazonaws.com:11729> set testkey testvalue
QUEUED
ec2-54-83-60-31.compute-1.amazonaws.com:11729> exec
1) OK
ec2-54-83-60-31.compute-1.amazonaws.com:11729> keys *
1) testkey
ec2-54-83-60-31.compute-1.amazonaws.com:11729> get testkey
testvalue
ec2-54-83-60-31.compute-1.amazonaws.com:11729>
```

Here's the my code, and how executing it looks.

```
var redis = require('redis');
var rdsclt = redis.createClient(process.env.REDIS_URL);
console.log('Before test block.');
console.log('rdsclt.flushall();');
rdsclt.flushall();
console.log('rdsclt.watch(\'testkey\');');
rdsclt.watch('testkey');
console.log('rdsclt.multi();');
rdsclt.multi();
console.log('rdsclt.set(\'testkey\', \'testvalue\');');
rdsclt.set('testkey', 'testvalue');
console.log('rdsclt.exec( (error, results) => {');
rdsclt.exec( (error, results) => {
    console.log('Inside test block exec callback.');
    console.log('error =',   JSON.stringify(error) );
    console.log('results =', JSON.stringify(results) );
});
console.log('After test block.');
return 0;  // Hopefully, indicates success, in Unix.

2016-11-07T19:39:20.038712+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2016-11-07T19:39:22.685896+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-11-07T19:39:22.685912+00:00 app[web.1]: > cubsredistest@1.0.0 start /app
2016-11-07T19:39:22.685913+00:00 app[web.1]: > node main.js
2016-11-07T19:39:22.685914+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-11-07T19:39:22.918869+00:00 app[web.1]: Before test block.
2016-11-07T19:39:22.919519+00:00 app[web.1]: rdsclt.flushall();
2016-11-07T19:39:22.920435+00:00 app[web.1]: rdsclt.watch('testkey');
2016-11-07T19:39:22.920662+00:00 app[web.1]: rdsclt.multi();
2016-11-07T19:39:22.920903+00:00 app[web.1]: rdsclt.set('testkey', 'testvalue');
2016-11-07T19:39:22.920959+00:00 app[web.1]: rdsclt.exec( (error, results) => {
2016-11-07T19:39:22.921021+00:00 app[web.1]: After test block.
2016-11-07T19:39:22.937915+00:00 app[web.1]: Inside test block exec callback.
2016-11-07T19:39:22.938011+00:00 app[web.1]: error = {"command":"EXEC","code":"ERR"}
2016-11-07T19:39:22.938287+00:00 app[web.1]: results = undefined
2016-11-07T19:39:00+00:00 app[heroku-redis]: source=REDIS sample#active-connections=1 sample#load-avg-1m=0.09 sample#load-avg-5m=0.13 sample#load-avg-15m=0.1 sample#read-iops=0 sample#write-iops=0 sample#memory-total=15664468.0kB sample#memory-free=13536884.0kB sample#memory-cached=694560kB sample#memory-redis=289016bytes sample#hit-rate=1 sample#evicted-keys=0
```

I would have said these two should yield the same results, and yet they don't.  I'm using the redis client that is installed using `npm install redis` .   I know there are other clients.

Does anybody know what's going on?

---

I changed the node client from node_redis to ioredis. 
Changed from `npm install redis` to `npm install ioredis`.
Now the error message is more informative.

```
2016-11-07T20:28:02.704282+00:00 app[web.1]: Inside test block exec callback.
2016-11-07T20:28:02.704615+00:00 app[web.1]: error = {"name":"ReplyError","message":"ERR EXEC without MULTI","command":{"name":"exec","args":[]}}
2016-11-07T20:28:02.704620+00:00 app[web.1]: results = undefined
2016-11-07T20:27:43+00:00 app[heroku-redis]: source=REDIS sample#active-connecti
```

Still haven't solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Arghh!  An example from node_redis' tests is:

```
    it('does not execute transaction if watched key was modified prior to execution', function (done) {
        client.WATCH(watched);
        client.incr(watched);
        var multi = client.multi();
        multi.incr(watched);
        multi.exec(helper.isNull(done));
    });
```

What I was doing is this:

```
    it('does not execute transaction if watched key was modified prior to execution', function (done) {
        client.WATCH(watched);
        client.incr(watched);
        client.multi();
        client.incr(watched);
        client.exec(helper.isNull(done));
    });
```

I'll leave this here.  Maybe it'll help the next person.